# Find vector at angle 90 to input vector

Tags: c#, geometry

I have input vector with random position and I want to find a vector at 90 deg to this vector. I know there is infinite vectors which achieve that scenario, but i need only one, doesnt matter which one.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any answers?

Comment: Yes. Should I accept cross product or your verision? I didnt investigate your alogirthm, but I will sonn, now im playig starcraft :P

Answer (score 4):

Compute the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) between your vector and a random other vector.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done for `v=(x,y,z)` I use the following algorithm to get two perpendicular vectors

```
if x<>0 or y<>0
   n_1 = (-x*z, -y*z, x^2+y^2 )
   n_2 = (-y, x, 0 )
else
   n_1 = (1, 0, 0)
   n_2 = (0, 1, 0)
```

Show that the dot products are zero.

```
n_1·v = (-x*z,-y*z,x^2+y^2)·(x,y,z) = -x^2*z-y^2*z+(x^2+y^2)*z = 0
n_2·v = (-y, x, 0)·(x,y,z) = -y*x+x*y+0 = 0
```